# Retrofit produces null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Hey stack overflow users, I am beginner in android development. Today I start making app for complaint management. While implementing register activity I got null pointer exception I don't know what is wrong with my code. For networking request I am using `retrofit library`. Here is my code what I done so far, Any suggestions, help will be much appreciated.

**Retrofit API Interface:**

```
package com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app;

import com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app.ModelResponse.RegisterResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface RetroFitApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("signup")
    Call<RegisterResponse> registerUser(
            @Field("un") String userName,
            @Field("pass") String password
    );
}
```

**Retrofit Client:**

```
package com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.107.97:8020/";
    private static RetrofitClient retrofitClient ;

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient()
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance()
    {
        if(retrofitClient == null)
        {
            retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return retrofitClient;
    }

    public RetroFitApiInterface getApi()
    {
        return retrofit.create(RetroFitApiInterface.class);

    }
}
```

**Pojo Class:**

```
package com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app.ModelResponse;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class  RegisterResponse {
//    pojo class
//    variables with annotations for mapping json
    @SerializedName("error")
    String error;
    @SerializedName("code")
    String code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;
    @SerializedName("data")
    String data;

    public RegisterResponse() {
    }

    public RegisterResponse(String error, String code, String message, String data) {
        this.error = error;
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity Java:**

```
package com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app.ModelResponse.RegisterResponse;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import java.util.Objects;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //register activity type casting
    TextInputEditText regUsername,regPassword,reg_cpassword;
    TextView loginLink;
    Button regButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //hiding action bar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //hide status bar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //register activity variables
        regUsername = findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        regPassword = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        reg_cpassword = findViewById(R.id.reg_cpassword);
        loginLink = findViewById(R.id.link_login);
        regButton = findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);

        //register click events
        regButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        loginLink.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.reg_btn:
//               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                registerUser();
               break;
            case R.id.link_login:
                switchOnLogin();

        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String userName = Objects.requireNonNull(regUsername.getText()).toString();
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(regPassword.getText()).toString();
        String cPass = Objects.requireNonNull(reg_cpassword.getText()).toString();

        if (userName.isEmpty()){
            regUsername.requestFocus();
            regUsername.setError("Please enter username");
            return;
        }if(password.isEmpty()){
            regPassword.requestFocus();
            regPassword.setError("Please enter your password");
            return;
        }if(cPass.isEmpty()){
            reg_cpassword.requestFocus();
            reg_cpassword.setError("Please enter confirm password");
            return;
        }

        Call <RegisterResponse> regCall = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .registerUser(userName,password);
        regCall.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Response<RegisterResponse> response) {
                RegisterResponse res = response.body();
                Log.e("response","res"+response.body());
                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message success = "+response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else{

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message error = "+response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void switchOnLogin() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**Api JSON:**

> ```
> {
>     "error": "true",
>     "code": "01",
>     "message": "Username haseebbbbbbb already exists. Try again with different username. Suggestions are haseebbbbbbb2901",
>     "data": ""
> }
> ```

**Log cat error:**

> 2022-01-27 09:49:37.245 3712-3712/com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app, PID: 3712
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
> com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app.ModelResponse.RegisterResponse.getMessage()'
> on a null object reference
> at com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:101)
> at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$retrofit2-DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
> at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown
> Source:6)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> 2022-01-27 09:49:37.265 3712-3712/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3712 SIG: 9

Comment: did you check the response using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)? From the error logs, it appears that `getMessage()` is being called from a null pointer reference. In other words, the response you're getting is null for some reason.

Comment: on a different note, I would recommend not using `response.body()` more than once. Since you've stored it in `RegisterResponse res` variable, use that instead.

Comment: Can you try replacing `Log.e("response","res"+response.body());` with `Log.e("response","res"+res);` and let me know if everything works?

Comment: @ganjaam res variable has null value:  2022-01-27 10:52:09.829 5342-5342/com.fwo.onenetwork.pwm.app E/response: resnull

Comment: @ganjaam yes I tried but res variable has null . I mention above

Comment: @ganjaam api gives response in postman I mention in question

Comment: @ganjaam no its not working

Comment: In your `MainActivity` you attempt `response.message()` on the response being successful and unsuccessful, do you know if the response is success?  I mean if the response is a failure, do you get a message that conforms to your pojo?  Is there a printout of the response in the log before your error, can you add a logo statement to both branches of the if statement to determine which is being executed?